# ActivityまたはFragmentの再生成中に非同期処理から値を受け取る場合の対応

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-activity

縦横回転等で`Activity`または`Fragment`再生成中にコールバックを受けて処理を行うと
`getActivity()`や`getView()`で`NullPointerException`や`IllegalArgumentException`で落ちてしまうと思います。

一般的に再生成中にコールバックを返しUI操作を行う可能性がある処理について
どのようにコーディングすればいいのかをご教授頂けますでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

通信などのコールバックされる先は、呼び出し元のインスタンスになると思います。
ですので、非同期処理を呼び出したあとに画面を回転させて`Fragment`が再生成した場合、コールバックされるのは既に`onDestroy()`済の古い`Fragment`になります。

先日、私が同じような質問をして回答がありました。
私のプログラムは、その回答を参考にして正常に動作しています。この方法で解決出来ませんか？
[通信中に画面回転した場合に通信結果を受け取り、画面に表示する方法について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/6304/)

上記の質問解決後も多少調べていたのですが、EventBusでも出来そうです。（まだ試していません）

EventBus参考
http://qiita.com/KeithYokoma/items/793aaac6994c9242808f

Comment: 有難うございました。
全く同じ質問が直近であったんですね・・・
quesera2さんの回答がまさに求めていた答えでした。
EventBus に関しては追加で調べてみます。